# How to instantiate outside of a constructor?

Tags: c#, autofac

How to replicate this code with Autofac syntax?

```
public static class MenuConfig
    {
        public static void Initialize()
        {
            var _menuService = DependecyFactory.GetInstance<IMenuService>(); 
            Parameters.Menu = _menuService.Menu();
        }
    }
```

Before calling this a "duplicate question" please note that I'm looking for an Autofac command. I CANNOT inject the interface anywhere and then call "Resolve". What I need to is perform an "InstancePerRequest" inline and uninjected so I don't have to do this:

```
var _service = new Service(new Dependency(new context()));
```

LightInject has a method that allows instantiation from an interface OUTSIDE of a constructor like this:

```
var _service = DependecyFactory.GetInstance<IService>();
```

What is the equivalent method for Autofac?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using Autofac as a service locator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7190795/using-autofac-as-a-service-locator)

Comment: Be more specific on what you're trying to do...

Comment: What do you mean with outside of a constructor? You have a constructor, I suppose? And the class you're working in can be registered with Autofac, right?

Comment: This is an edge case scenario. I have a static class that requires database data at startup. I cannot instantiate a static class, so I need a way to fetch the data from my service. With LightInject, this is easy. How do I do the same with Autofac?

Comment: Can't you change that static class into a non-static class and register it as singleton instead?

Comment: Creating a new object **always** end up calling a constructor, some way or another. DI containers try to hide that call, but ultimately it's always there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simply not possible with Autofac. All other solutions involving Autofac will require code refactoring which may potentially break software functionality. So unfortunately, the most elegant and least disruptive solution is this:

```
var _service = new Service(new Dependency(new context()));
```

Since this is an edge case addressing only one part of the software, this compromise is acceptable. It would be nice, however, if Autofac implemented this functionality in some future release.

Answer (score 0):

When calling `containerBuilder.Build()` you get back a container which implements `IContainer` and `ILifetimeScope`, whenever you get hold of one of these interfaces, you can resolve types from it:

```
container.Resolve<IService>();
```

If you want this container to be static, you could add the container as a static property to the `Program` or `Startup` class (depending if you're creating a Console or ASP.NET application).

Remember that the root container will be around for the entire duration of your application, so this can result in unwanted memory leaks when used incorrectly. Also see the warning in the [documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/index.html).

Still, it's perfectly possible to do the memory management yourself by resolving an `Owned<>` version from your interface:

```
using (var service = Program.Container.Resolve<Owned<IService>>())
{
    service.Value.UseService();
}
```

Anyway, since you mention a static class in the comments, the best solution is to change that into a non-static class and register it as a singleton with Autofac. Then you can inject a `Func<Owned<IService>> serviceFactory` into that singleton and create/dispose an instance of the service wherever you need it.

```
using (var service = serviceFactory())
{
    service.Value.UseService();
}
```

Comment: As mentioned in [the documentation](https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/resolve/index.html), you should not resolve directly from the root container.

Comment: Yeah one needs to be aware of that idd. Creating a lifetimescope that lives for the duration of the program doesn't solve this problem though, so other solutions need to be used. I've updated my answer.

Comment: So bottom line: There is NO equivalent Autofac command to do what LightInject does, correct? I briefly looked into the Singleton pattern, but was unable to fully grasp and implement it. I will look into that some more because I think THAT'S the proper way to do it. The LightInject method is quick and easy and very useful for these types of scenarios. I was hoping I didn't have to REDESIGN the original code with Autofac.

Comment: Well, in future you'll know to avoid static classes in combination with DI and a whole new world will open up (f.e. unit-testing, which is probably impossible with that static class + LightInject).

Comment: Btw you don't need to lookup the Singleton pattern. What I meant is just a non-static class that you register `AsSingleton` with Autofac (as a replacement for your static class).

Comment: AsSingleton is not a method of the builder class:

Comment: builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(MenuService).Assembly)
               .Where(t => t.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
               .AsSingleton
               .InstancePerRequest();

Comment: You can't combine `AsSingleton` with `InstancePerRequest`. Also, I do hope not all your services are singletons (you said this was an edge-case). Better register services with `InstancePerLifetimeScope()`. But I know too little about your project to give any good advice. Getting DI right is not always an easy task; you constantly need to think about the lifetime of objects. Some objects need to have only one instance f.e. a message bus or configuration service, others need an instance per lifetimescope, f.e. mailService, loginService, userService, repositories, data context, etc.